# Odoo @api.onchange('zip') not working

Tags: field, odoo, onchange

Whenever I apply and onchange on the 'zip' or 'city' field on the res.partner form nothing happens.

Other fields work just fine, only those 2 don't give any result.

Code:

```
class myclass(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.partner'

@api.onchange('zip')
def myfunctuin(self):
    #this is a test
    self.name = "test"
```

Comment: Have you managed to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

onchange method is actually working, insert this line into onchange method:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and you will see that method is actually working.

Comment: No this didn't do anything for either 'zip' or 'city'

Comment: does odoo stoped? if odoo start debugging it means that this method is actually working, and you must change "algorythm"

Comment: Hey no it didn't stopped, and also didn't start debugging. I noticed that the city and zip fields are slightly moved but I never changed this in the view.xml file

Comment: generally onchange method will run in stage when object is creating, so on that moment objects id may be newID that means that object isn't created yet, and you onchange may not work properly, with this code fragment i cant help you, but it seems that u wrote something wrong there

Comment: that is what I was thinking to, strange that this only applies to those two fields than..